# After install RestSharp, Visual Studio debugging got error: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, rest, restsharp

I would like to use RestSharp, but after install RestSharp, runing Visual Studio debugging got error: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!